# Test a counter in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Bellow i added the code of my counter component. Now i want to test it with only JEST.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Counter() {

    const [state, setState] = useState(0);

    function counterFun() {
        setState(state + 1)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={counterFun}>Counter</button>

            <h1>Counter is:{state} </h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Counter;
```

I wrote my test bellow:

```js
   

import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import Counter from './Counter';
import { shallow, configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

it('increment count by 1 when button clicked', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Counter />);
    const incrementBtn = wrapper.find('button');
    incrementBtn.simulate('click')
    const text = wrapper.find('h1').text();
    expect(text).toEqual('Counter is: 1');
  })
```

..but i am not sure that it is correct. I want to test if my counter works after each click event. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

look at this code to test counter Just you have to use enzyme and import shallow

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

it('increment count by 1 when button clicked', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Counter />);
    const incrementBtn = wrapper.find('button.increment');
    incrementBtn.simulate('click')
    const text = wrapper.find('h1').text();
    expect(text).toEqual('Counter is: 1');
  })
```

Comment: Shoudn't be `h1` in `find`? In the component there is `<h1>Counter is:{state} </h1>`.

Comment: @niks, i changed my test to in the main code, but it si not working
``

Comment: @niks The issue is solved. There was a problem in an extra space in my html markup. I changed: <h1>Counter is:{state} </h1> to <h1>Counter is:{state}</h1>

Comment: oh that was strange... anyways great

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. There was a problem in an extra space in my html markup.
I changed: `<h1>Counter is:{state} </h1>` to `<h1>Counter is:{state}</h1>`